# The Apple-authored driver appletmp.sys halts Windows 7 startup on Macbook Air

Tags: bootcamp, windows, multi-touch

Following a Windows Update which required a reboot, Windows 7 (64 bit) cannot launch successfully.  The Windows System Recovery tool has been unable to fix the problem with any of the recovery points I have tried.  The only system image available is from the same time as the Windows Update, so it seems pointless to try.

[This thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2633636) on the Apple Discussions board has more details.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, according to the thread you linked, mentions that: *The only solution that I have found is to disable the two Apple Multitouch devices listed in the Device Manager and use an external USB mouse while running your updates.*. So if your OS doesn’t boot anymore, you’ll likely have to reinstall it (using an external mouse this time). You can install windows on top of windows without losing your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing a fresh install of Windows 7 and leaving the trackpad off.  It probably makes sense to keep a USB mouse handy.